# Go To takes forever in visual studio code jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to use visual studio code for jupyter notebook.

[image]

I click on run all, it shows "Go To" and "Go To" gets displayed forever. The code never runs:

[image]

It is the global environment I am using. Changing the environment does not help.

Comment: Go To ? What is that supposed to do?

Comment: I click run all, it shows "Go To". The code does not run.

Comment: Ah. Well, the Go To means go to the most recently failed cell. So that's why it appears. You seem to be unable to run the code for some reason. My VSCode tells me I don't have ipykernel package installed. You should probably review all the steps for working with notebooks in VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks. In particular the note about installing the jupyter package (you probably can and should make sure you have the notebook extension - or maybe that is just the same thing).